# setTimeout inside setInterval does not work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

My code should change the class of the item in every second and repeat it forever.

```js
function myFunction() {
 setInterval(function() {
    $("#item").addClass("class-one").removeClass("class-two");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#item").addClass("class-two").removeClass("class-one");
    }, 1000);
  },1000);
}

myFunction();
```

First time the code works well, but after the loop starts again, it starts switching very fast. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's likely a way of doing what you want without using `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

Comment: I want to repeat the switching, I tried using while (true) but it's crashes out the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The interval starts
2. 1 second later the interval resolves:

- classes are switched over
- the timeout is triggered

3. 1 second later:

   - The timeout resolves

     - classes are switched over
   - The interval resolves

     - classes are switched over
     - the timeout is triggered

You probably want the timeout time to be **half** the interval time, not the **same** as it.

---

A better approach entirely would be to use **one** class and use `jQuery().toggle` to toggle it on and off every second (using one interval and no timeouts).

Comment: thanks! halving the settimeout's delay solved the problem. .toggle() is not good for me, I need both classes

Answer (score 1):

correct way :

```js
var i = 0;
function myFunction() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      $("#item").addClass("class-one").removeClass("class-two");
    } else {
      $("#item").addClass("class-two").removeClass("class-one");
    }
    i++;
  },1000);
}

myFunction();
```

or with your solution : ( increase 1 second of setInterval time )

```js
function myFunction() {
 setInterval(function() {
    $("#item").addClass("class-one").removeClass("class-two");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#item").addClass("class-two").removeClass("class-one");
    }, 1000);
  },2000);
}

myFunction();
```